# unix split skip first n of lines

Tags: unix, split, gnu

I have a rather large file I need to split.  However, I don't need the first 1000 lines.  I would like to start the split at line 1001 and then continue to split the file by 1000.  I know how to split by 1000, that is no problem.

**CODE**:

```
split --lines=1000 *.txt
```

However, I want to skip the first 1000 lines.  Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Why bother?  Simply don't use the first generated file.  `sed 1,1000d *.txt | split --lines=1000 -` should do the job.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `tail -n +1001` to get lines starting from 1001st line:

```
cat *.txt | tail -n +1001 | split --lines=1000
```

Comment: what is the cat command used for?  is that just another way to merge the files?  I am already working with a large merge. @falsetru

Comment: @JDE876, Yes, that is for merge.

Comment: Great!  I mainly need the "tail -n +1001 | split --lines=1000" since the file is already merged. It works perfect. It is very great to know you can use ' | ' to do multiple commands.  That is something new, thanks! @falsetru

Answer (score 0):

@JDE876 : We can even get the desired output using perl one liner

```
perl -ne "print if $. > 1000" file
```